# Create custom paypal button with link direct after payment

Tags: file, button, paypal, download

I am trying to create a custom paypal  button for selling digital goods, that will direct the buyer to a link that will allow him to download the file.

I've read a bit this paypal article about advanced html variables but I am not sure which I have to use to make it work: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Obviously the download should only initiate based on the payment ID to prevent free downloads, or is that done automatically by paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend us utilizing [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to handle all your post-payment processing tasks like updating your database, sending out email notifications (including one with a download link), etc.

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies
>   you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use IPN messages
>   to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as
>   fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other
>   transaction-related information.

This will allow you to not only automate the procedures, but also correctly handle things like e-checks or any other type of payment that may originally be in a "pending" status.  You wouldn't want to deliver the digital goods until that payment actually clears.  With IPN you will get 1 notification that your script can handle when the payment comes through as pending, and you would get another one when the payment updates to Completed, or Failed, or whatever.

The IPN's happen in real-time so buyers won't have to wait on anything.  Whatever you're doing within the script would happen instantly upon the transaction completing.

Comment: Do I really need a database? I am not that good at web development so I was hoping the code that checks if the payment was suscessful is done automatically by Paypal, or does it have to happen on my website?

Comment: No, you don't need a database  I was just saying if you do happen to be doing database updates, that's where you'd want to do it.  If you're not doing that, though, no problem.  You can automate whatever procedures you are indeed using and need to automate.